# Casting std::any back to its original type?

Tags: c++, casting, std, c++17

Is there a way to cast std::any back to its original type without having to hard code it?

I know you can do

```
std::any_cast<int>(example)
```

But this requires you do already know that "example" is an int. I noticed that std::any stores the original type but I can't seem to find anyway to use it for casting. I want to do something like this:

```
static_cast<example.type()>(example);
```

Sorry if this is a bit of a basic question but I feel like this may just not be possible and wanted to check.

Comment: It can check the cast, but it doesn't (and can't) know the type directly.

Comment: I think it's time to rethink your design

Comment: I agree, I am trying to implement a custom stack that can store any data you pass it, I can easily store the data using templates or std::any but I can never cast it back so it is useless.

Comment: @CalumMcManus what use case do you see for a heterogenous container that can holy **any data** type?

Comment: @CalumMcManus one thing you could do is to keep another stack with integers that represent each data type - this doesnt scale well AT ALL But might help you do whatever you are trying to do

Comment: @PYA then you better use `std::variant` ...

Comment: I am trying to make a very small program that handles complex scientific computations. I was hoping compress memory management into a single stack of instructions that could range from individual numbers to structs and classes containing large algorithms.

Comment: @bolov I agree, was just trying to help OP achieve his primary goal :)

Comment: @CalumMcManus it sounds like ordinary templated algorithms would do. Can you give an example in your question of what you want the end result to resemble?

Comment: @alterigel Basically I want 1 stack that I can pass a large range of structs, classes, numbers and characters too so that I can pop out data and instructions in order.

Comment: @CalumMcManus for language parsing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because the type of the cast must be known at compile time and the type held in a `std::any` instance is known at runtime.

I want to point here that `std::any` use cases are very very limited. You should probably never use it in an end-user facing code. Its role is a type safe alternative to `void*`. One use case that I can think of is in the implementation of some type-erasure class where previously `void*` would have been used (something like `std::function` maybe).

Think carefully if `std::any` is really what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also thinging about this recently. We hope std::any has a method to get the original type instend of returning type_info. But this can not be implemented now unless C++ add the dynamic feature or runtime reflection like Java.

But I come up with a workaround. We store the "operation" in std::function instead of storing data in std::any.

Suppose we want to store different data and print and write them to file later.

```
//Solution1 use std::any
temlate<typename... T>
std::vector<std::any> prepare_data(T... t);
auto data=prepare_data(10,-1,0.5,3.3,"abcd",....); 
//....
void print_and_write(std::vector<std::any> data)
{
  for (....)
  {
     print(...)
     write(...)
  }
}
```

```
//Solution2 use std::function
temlate<typename... T>
std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> prepare_data(T... t);
auto operation=[](auto data){print(data);write(data);};
auto data=prepare_data(
         std::bind(operation,10),
         std::bind(operation,3.3),
         std::bind(operation,"abcd"),
         ...........
); 

void print_and_write(std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> data)
{
    for(...)
    {
        data[i]();//perform the lambda
    }
}
```